# Dividing rows by a set of conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

I am comparing the maximum likelihood of my raw data to a modified dataset. For the modified dataset, I need to create a function that divides a row into two rows if a value for a parameter exceeds a specific value. For instance, the base dataset looks like this:

```
Year ID Displacement
1999  A  38
1999  B  15
2001  B  19
2003  C  17
```

For the modified dataset, I want to divide that 38 in row one into two rows of 19. Like below:

```
Year ID Displacement
1999  A  19
1999  A  19
1999  B  15
2001  B  19
2003  C  17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
df2 <- df[with(df, c(rep(which(Displacement >= 38), 2), which(Displacement < 38))), ];
df2$Displacement[df2$Displacement >= 38] <- df2$Displacement[df2$Displacement >= 38] / 2;
#    Year ID Displacement
#1   1999  A           19
#1.1 1999  A           19
#2   1999  B           15
#3   2001  B           19
#4   2003  C           17
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Year ID Displacement
1999  A  38
1999  B  15
2001  B  19
2003  C  17", header = T)
```

Comment: Yes, that will work but my dataset has 10,000 rows. Is there a way to code for, if a value exceeds 19 (the mean of my full dataset), divide that 38 by 2?

Comment: @Constantin-GeorgeGlen I’ve made some changes to my solution; please take a look.

Comment: Why did you do use 2 in c(rep(which(Displacement >= 38), 2)?

Comment: @Constantin-GeorgeGlen `rep(which(Displacement >= 38), 2)` duplicates (hence `2`) those rows where `Displacement >= 38`.